# angular.js how to parse variable data inside view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this variable:

```
var number = "1,10,25,60";
```

How can I parse it inside a view into this form?

```
<tr>
   <td ng-click="ctrl.set(1)>1</td>
   <td ng-click="ctrl.set(10)>10</td>
   <td ng-click="ctrl.set(25)>25</td>
   <td ng-click="ctrl.set(60)>60</td>
</tr>
```

In normal js I would just do `var numbers = number.split(",");` and then some loop like so:

```
var html;
for (i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
   html += "<td ng-click='ctrl.set" + numbers[i] + "'>" + numbers[i] + "</td>";
}
```

Maybe some directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign it to a `$scope` var (the split result)

```
var number = "1,10,25,60";
$scope.numbers = number.split(",");
```

And the view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="num in numbers">
    <td ng-click="ctrl.set(num)>{{num}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: well but I don't have that variable inside js file, it's inside view

Comment: What do you mean, it's in the view?

Comment: well, I got an array of items and each has its own numbers. So I just can't do that like your example, but I will try to figure out something

Comment: If you could post what you actually have, it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` will iterate through an array:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js"></script>
   </head>
<body  ng-app  >
    <input ng-model="$scope.numbers" ng-init="$scope.numbers = [1,10,25,60]"/>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="n in $scope.numbers track by $index"
              ng-click="console.log(n);$scope.selected = n">{{n}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>{{$scope.selected}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dont use `$scope` in the view files!

Comment: Don't use `$scope` at all, use controllerAs!  But this demo showing `ng-repeat` is all defined in the HTML.